# 1 file descriptor for multiple threads, shows multiple open files on losf

Tags: c++, linux, file, file-descriptor

I have a program with ~200 threads active at a time. When I open a fd, I know it is shared between the threads.

In `/proc/[pid]/fd` I can see really only 1 fd, but when looking at all the open files, using `lsof` I can see the file is opened for each thread. (e.g. same file shows 200 times, with same pid, and different tid)

What is the reason for that?

Also, I need to have different threads writing to the same file (different locations). Is it thread safe to use this 1 fd? (does not make sense to me, but if the file is opened once per thread already, as shown by `lsof` it could be safe).

Comment: Mostly unrelated to your question, but unless most of the threads you have are idle most of the time, or you have a workstation with way more than 32 CPU cores or so, then having around 200 threads might be overkill and might actually impact performance negatively. Synchronization between threads (which ***is*** needed if they write to the same file) is definitely going to be a major performance inhibitor.

Comment: not all 200 threads are writing to the file, only 3 at once.
And yes, synchronization is a big challenge, but its a systems that scales, and the hardware can support it.

Comment: Then it's much less of a problem. While the writes themselves are atomic (see [the `write` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)) the order between threads are not guaranteed. I would really recommend you to try and redesign or refactor so that no more than one threads write to one file.

Comment: oh thank you, missed the part about the offset setting being atomic with the writes, guess that solves the problem.

Comment: @OrDinari You can use `pwrite()` to write directly to any file offset you like without needing to seek, so you don't need to using a locking scheme around each `lseek()`/`write()` pair - because if you use `lseek()` then `write()`, you **DO** have to lock that.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pwrite.html and http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html  Note that if you open the file in append mode, `pwrite()` on Linux is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lsof` lists the file for each "thread" because Linux threads aren't true threads because of the underlying OS design.

The first threads on Linux were ["LinuxThreads"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinuxThreads):

> In the Linux operating system, LinuxThreads was a partial
>   implementation of POSIX Threads. It has since been superseded by the
>   Native POSIX Thread Library (NPTL).[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinuxThreads) The main developer of
>   LinuxThreads was Xavier Leroy.
>
> LinuxThreads had a number of problems, mainly owing to the
>   implementation, which used the clone system call to create a new
>   process sharing the parent's address space. For example, threads had
>   distinct process identifiers, causing problems for signal handling;
>   LinuxThreads used the signals SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 for inter-thread
>   coordination, meaning these signals could not be used by programs.
>
> To improve the situation, two competing projects were started to
>   develop a replacement; NGPT (Next Generation POSIX Threads) and NPTL.
>   NPTL won out and is today shipped with the vast majority of Linux
>   systems.

LinuxThreads were replaced by NPTL - [Native POSIX Thread Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library).  But there is still a fundamental lack of actual, full kernel-level threads:

> **Design**
>
> NPTL uses a similar approach to LinuxThreads, in that **the primary abstraction known by the kernel is still a process**, and new
>   threads are created with the clone() system call (called from the NPTL
>   library).

Most of the time, the fact that Linux lacks full kernel-level threads isn't apparent.

And it really doesn't matter how the OS handles concurrent processing.

But that's why `lsof` list the file as open by multiple "processes".  Because it is.  It's just that those "processes" share the same address space, along with a lot of other resources.

Note that one of the "shared resources" is the current offset of an open file descriptor - if you change the offset in one thread, you change it for all threads in the process.

If need to write to a file open via one file descriptor from multiple threads, you can use [the `pwrite()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pwrite.html) to atomically write to an arbitrary location in the file, without regard to the descriptor's current offset:

> ```
> #include <unistd.h>
>
> ssize_t pwrite(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte,
>        off_t offset);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The `pwrite()` function shall be equivalent to `write()`, except that
>   it writes into a given position and does not change the file offset
>   (regardless of whether `O_APPEND` is set). The first three arguments to
>   `pwrite()` are the same as `write()` with the addition of a fourth
>   argument `offset` for the desired position inside the file. An attempt
>   to perform a `pwrite()` on a file that is incapable of seeking shall
>   result in an error.

Note that on Linux, if you open the file with `O_APPEND`, [`pwrite()` is broken](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html):

> **BUGS**
>
> POSIX requires that opening a file with the `O_APPEND` flag should
>   have no effect on the location at which `pwrite()` writes data. 
>   However, on Linux, if a file is opened with `O_APPEND`, `pwrite()`
>   appends data to the end of the file, regardless of the value of
>   *offset*.